# Extremely High CPU Usage on Apche on Google Cloud

Tags: apache, cpu-usage, gcloud

Im a hardware developer and my friend has a website on google cloud. Suddenly the cpu usage goes extremely high. Even refreshing a page with one line causes the CPU usage to sky rocket. 
It uses expression engine and runs an apache server. It has a mysql database. The specs of the machine are
3 GHz 1 core
3.75 GB RAM

Please let me know what other information i need to add

Im not good with networks at all. The main reason im here is because the server runs linux and Im  the only one he knows that knows to use it.

Edit: The main process that eats the CPU usage is Apache 2. There are a lot of instances that combined takes around 80%. So if there are 10 apache processes wach one would take around 7 - 9%. If there were 6 apache each one takes around 10 - 13 %. What i want to know is whether i the system needs upgrading or if it is a configuration error. I have already reduced the max client from 150 to 10. Now the memory overflow does not happen, but the cpu usage is still 100%

Comment: Please add the website so I can take a look at the code.

Comment: I am not sure how to handle your question. CPU usage is primarily determined by the code you have and processes that are running, should not have anything to do with machine specifications *alone*. All I can recommend is to find *which* process is eating the CPU and trace it. As it is currently written, it will be hard to get good answer to your question on Stackoverflow. Do take a look at our help center for our [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide.

Comment: The process that is taking maximum cpu time is apache. There are a lot of apache processes running at once. Initially it had 15 apache processes each taking 5%. I reduced the max client to 10 and now each process takes 8-9% One thing i want to know is whether 1 virtual CPU is enough to handle all these requests. Should i add more resources

Comment: Does restarting the VM help lessen the load in any way?